# S.M.A.R.T. Error MacOS 11 Big Sur Beta Installer

Tags: macos, ssd, storage, beta, big-sur

Mid-2014 MacBook Pro 13" lowest spec.

I recently upgraded the SSD to a 500GB WD Blue NVMe M.2 drive. I suspect the given issue may be something to do about this upgraded SSD. I have three partitions on the drive, one (really two, Data and System) for macOS, one for Bootcamp, and one for Shared files.

I am running macOS 11 Big Sur Developer Beta 1 as of now. I saw an available update today for what I assume to be the public beta. I downloaded the 12 GB .app installer, and once I got to the 'select a drive' phase, all three partitions were grayed out with the error:

`This disk has S.M.A.R.T. errors.` The popup (in an attached screenshot) specified that this was a hardware issue, although the drive is less than a month old.

Before everyone renounces me for even thinking of installing the developer beta on my mac (I do understand how incredibly buggy macOS betas are), I want to assure all the veterans this is not my main machine, although I do use it for application development and various other uses. I don't want to run a clean install though, as this machine does have data and I am tired of wiping it on numerous occasions. I have only seen minor bugs, UI glitches, and slowdowns over the period of about a month of using this beta. In any case, any help debugging this problem is welcome.

Here's a screenshot: [image]

Answer (score 3):

I would load the app [DriveDX](https://binaryfruit.com/drivedx) which specifically looks for the SMART status of the drives. The app is not free but has a free trial period. You can use that to check your drive. It will tell you the SMART status and details about the drive. It very simple to use. Just start the app and it will start scanning your drives. Give it a minute or so to complete and display the results. See the image below for an example of the output. Yes my drives are failing or have failed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would install Homebrew ([brew.sh](https://brew.sh)) if you don't have it already.

Then install smartmontools which provides a heck of a lot more data. This will provide far more detailed insight into the health of your disk. Read about it https://www.smartmontools.org

`brew install smartmontools`

`smartctl -a disk0` You can `diskutil -list` to get the drive id.

```
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [Darwin 17.7.0 x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     SandForce Driven SSDs
Device Model:     OWC Mercury Extreme Pro SSD
Serial Number:    MXE12010E48B0468
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000000 000000468
Firmware Version: 361A13F0
User Capacity:    120,034,123,776 bytes [120 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 6
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s
Local Time is:    Sat Jul 25 18:48:16 2020 EDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7f) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Abort Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   5) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   116   110   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0/145147714
  5 Retired_Block_Count     0x0033   100   100   003    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours_and_Msec 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       39376h+03m+21.330s
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   054   054   000    Old_age   Always       -       47865
171 Program_Fail_Count      0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
174 Unexpect_Power_Loss_Ct  0x0030   000   000   000    Old_age   Offline      -       6340
177 Wear_Range_Delta        0x0000   000   000   000    Old_age   Offline      -       2
181 Program_Fail_Count      0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   030   030   000    Old_age   Always       -       30 (Min/Max 30/30)
195 ECC_Uncorr_Error_Count  0x001c   116   110   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0/145147714
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0033   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
231 SSD_Life_Left           0x0013   099   099   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
233 SandForce_Internal      0x0000   000   000   000    Old_age   Offline      -       18752
234 SandForce_Internal      0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       20032
241 Lifetime_Writes_GiB     0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       20032
242 Lifetime_Reads_GiB      0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       35008

SMART Error Log not supported

SMART Self-test Log not supported

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: If you do not have Homebrew installed, you don't need to as you can download an Apple .dmg from: https://sourceforge.net/projects/smartmontools/files/smartmontools/7.1/